# Need to set the quartz cron expression dynamically

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I'm using quartz in my web application (Servlet web app) following is snap of quartz.property file and the quartz.job.xml

quartz.property

```
#===================================================
# Configure the Job Initialization Plugin
#===================================================

org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.class = org.quartz.plugins.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.fileNames = jobs.xml
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.failOnFileNotFound = true
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.scanInterval = 10
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.wrapInUserTransaction = false


<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<job-scheduling-data xmlns="http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/JobSchedulingData"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/JobSchedulingData http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/job_scheduling_data_1_8.xsd"
  version="1.8">

    <schedule>
        <job>
            <name>my-very-clever-job</name>
            <group>MYJOB_GROUP</group>

            <description>The job description</description>
            <job-class>com.acme.scheduler.job.ReportJob</job-class>
        </job>

        <trigger>
            <cron>
                <name>my-trigger</name>
                <group>MYTRIGGER_GROUP</group>
                <job-name>my-very-clever-job</job-name>

                <job-group>MYJOB_GROUP</job-group>
                <!-- trigger every night at 4:30 am -->
                <cron-expression>0 30 4 * * ?</cron-expression>

            </cron>
        </trigger>
    </schedule>
</job-scheduling-data>
```

Every thing work fine,in this order. I need to allow user to change the time (cron expression) as the way they want.My question is how do i set the cron expression in dynamically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CronTrigger cronTrigger = (CronTrigger) stdScheduler
                .getTrigger(triggerName,triggerGroupName);
CronTrigger newTriggerIns = new CronTrigger();
 newTriggerIns.setJobName(cronTrigger.getJobName());
 newTriggerIns.setName(triggerName);
 newTriggerIns.setCronExpression(newCronExpression);
 stdScheduler.rescheduleJob(triggerName,triggerGroupName,newTriggerIns);
```

In the above, take the existing trigger instance. 
Create one new trigger instance and set cron expression.

Then reschedule the existing instance with new one.

Comment: The principle here sounds right but the execution isn't possible with the current Spring implementation. CronTrigger is an abstract class so you must do what @atripathi notes below.

Comment: I had posted the above code, when it worked for me and now it is being used to reschedule a trigger.

Comment: Where do you insert this code? In the Job itself? I'm trying to do the same thing but am not sure how to create de stdScheduler. Thanks

Comment: I have Cron expression in my DB I'm fetching them.firstly how could I able to c check the Cron expression and then to trigger by Cron expression.

Comment: With Spring+Qartz you can get stdScheduler:
    @Autowire
    SchedulerFactoryBean factory;
    ...
    factory.getScheduler()

Answer (score 4):

Creating a new Trigger like this doesn't work.

```
CronTrigger cronTrigger = (CronTrigger) stdScheduler.getTrigger(triggerName,triggerGroupName);
CronTrigger newTriggerIns = new CronTrigger();
newTriggerIns.setJobName(cronTrigger.getJobName());
newTriggerIns.setName(triggerName);
newTriggerIns.setCronExpression(newCronExpression);
stdScheduler.rescheduleJob(triggerName,triggerGroupName,newTriggerIns); //doesn't work
```

You just have to edit the original trigger like this:

```
CronTrigger cronTrigger = (CronTrigger) stdScheduler.getTrigger(triggerName,triggerGroupName);
cronTrigger.setCronExpression(newCronExpression);
stdScheduler.rescheduleJob(triggerName,triggerGroupName,cronTrigger);
```

Comment: Where do you insert this code? In the Job itself? 
I'm trying to do the same thing but am not sure how to create de stdScheduler.
Thanks

Comment: No, not in the Job itself. Put this code outside the job, where ever you need to set the CRON expression.

Answer (score 0):

Use Quartz api. Programmatically take this trigger instance, cast it to CronTrigger instance and use it's setCronExpression to put expression dynamically.

Comment: Can you provide me a sample, is possible