# How to excute a method on particular date using Spring?

Tags: java, spring, date

I have got a list of dates, on these dates I have to execute particular method.
How do I proceed?

Comment: so, if i understand correctly. You have a list of dates in a variable within your program? and you need to execute a method on that day?

Comment: although it is possible to do that routinely work, I think it is not recommended to do that. you can have better option like `crontab` in `linux`

Answer (score 2):

Create a [quartz scheduler and configure cron trigger](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.2.5/reference/scheduling.html) to fire up your service on [particular date/time specified by comma separated cron expressions](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger)

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I had looked into quartz scheduler and configure cron trigger. Suppose if i have Dynamic List of dates .... is it like for every Date i have to schedule a cron trigger and going further if i amend one of the  date how will that be handled .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12208309/need-to-set-the-quartz-cron-expression-dynamically

Answer (score 2):

Check this cron trigger expression examples shown here. You will have to use a Quartz scheduler in Spring. 
This might be a good place to start off with the Taskexecuter in Spring too.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html

http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/tutorials/crontrigger