# Implementing scheduler in spring (defined by user)

Tags: java, spring-mvc, scheduling

I am developing spring mvc application.

I have gone through below links

1. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-scheduled
2. http://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-and-spring-taskscheduler-example/

These guide for how to schedule.

But I have to give it to the users, to schedule(run on daily/weekly basis etc.) some functionality from GUI.

Can any one please help me how can I achieve this?

Comment: what you want to schedule? Is this longer job?

Comment: Consider it as some kind of predefined tasks/job. I just want user to schedule it when to run. And tasks can be small of 5 min or it can be large like 4 hours or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have several tasks to be scheduled by user.

Define a Enum for the tasks names and a Runner to run task by enum. Define a job to be executed every second (minute, hour). The job just checks whether there is a user's task to be executed.

Now user defines such a task whith following params
TaskType  (the Enum value)
TaskTime (when it should be started e.g. 12:00)
TaskPeriod (how often it should be called)

TaskTime and TaskPeriod could be joined e.g. in cron expression.

Then all the task info is stored somewhere (e.g. in DB).

Your permanent Job every second reads from the DB whether there is a task to be executed. It checks task time and task period and compares with current time. If it's time to start it gets enum value and calls Runner's method for the enum.

Comment: I really like your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Please check the [link](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-from-the-trenches-using-environment-specific-cron-expressions-with-the-scheduled-annotation/). It explains how to schedule tasks by giving crone expressions in a property file.

Other solution is using the [quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) library directly. We can schedule or reschedule jobs easily using that. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12208309/need-to-set-the-quartz-cron-expression-dynamically).

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is assigning the value on server start up. But my requirement is, user can set the timing at runtime and can schedule same task multiple times.

Comment: I think it is not possible with the @scheduled annotation. If use the quartz library, you can easily reschedule the tasks.

Comment: Can you please provide some info/link for it.

Comment: I really appreciate the answer. It provides functionality to reschedule the task, but initially I will not have any task scheduled. User will set it from GUI.

Comment: No need to start a job initially, you can schedule a job on button click and in the next time, unschedule(http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/cookbook/UnscheduleJob) the first one and schedule it again. Or reschedule it using rescheduleJob() method. @NamanGala

Comment: It is quite interesting. I will try to implement this.